# Replace custom listview layout while clicking button in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, layout, custom-lists

I am having two buttons in one screen,When I click first button I am showing a list in custom listView in next screen. And when I click second button I need to replace the custom listview with another layout in next screen(which is same for both buttons )

Answer (score 1):

Please use below logic when you press buttons:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("is_show_custom_view",true);//pass false when you press second button
 startActivity(intent);
```

Now you have to get that boolean and appy logic like :

```
if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("is_show_custom_view")){
//Add here your code for custome view
}else{
//Add here your code for normal view
}
```